# How to redirect all url which not related to controllers (Asp.Net MVC)

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to always redirect to my home page if someone puts something like `www.example/bla/qwerty.hm` (it doesnt have controller and it doesnt exist) to `www.example.com`.

I want to redirect all urls, which have not controller, to my home page and not show error. For example: `www.example.com/auto` (auto is not controller) and it will be redirect to my home page. How do I do that?

1. I tried Route configuration

   ```
       routes.MapRoute(
           name: "MyRedirect"
           , url: "{contextRedirect}/{*tasks}"
           , defaults: new { controller = "Redirect", action = "TotalRedirect", contextRedirect = "" }
           );
   ```

   ...

   ```
       public ActionResult TotalRedirect(string contextRedirect)
   {
       return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
   }
   ```

but this is called every time and it makes an infinity loop (it is called every time when redirectToAction is called)

The problem disappears if I write all `RouteMaps` for all existing controllers before this `MapRoute`, but I have lot of controllers, and I want avoid writing `RouteMaps` for all controllers.

2. Instead of MapRoute I tried Web.config and change errors

   ```
       <customErrors mode="On">
             <error redirect="/Error" statusCode="404" />
             <error redirect="/Error" statusCode="500" />
           </customErrors>
   ```

   Error is controller which return `RedirectToAction` and I got same result as point 1 (infinity loop). But when I change `/Error` to `/Home` it is working (because Home return View), but on Url path is saved error text `Home?aspxerrorpath=/auto`. After redirect I do not want show text, that means if page will be redirected in to `www.example.com`, it not show `www.example/Home?aspxerrorpath=/auto`.

I am new to Asp.net MVC, and I don't know proper way how to do it.

---

### **Update**

After some research I think there are two ways how to do it.

1. (Thanks to KevinLamb) Redirect from error with Application_Error and Web.Confing httpError. This is working for me:

   This settings is put in Web.Confing on Project level, that means first Web.Config you see in Project Explorer (there is second Web.Config on View folder). Then you must create Controller named Error with ActionResult ErrorHandle

   ```
   <system.webServer>
       <httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
         <remove statusCode="404"/>
         <error statusCode="404" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/Error/ErrorHandle"/>
         <remove statusCode="400"/>
         <error statusCode="400" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/Error/ErrorHandle"/>
         <remove statusCode="500"/>
         <error statusCode="500" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/Error/ErrorHandle"/>
   </httpErrors>
   ```

   ...

   ```
   // Error Controller .cs
   namespace MyWebApp.Controllers
       {
           public class ErrorController : Controller
           {
               // GET: Error
               public ActionResult Index()
               {
                   return RedirectToAction("Home", "Index");
               }

               public ActionResult ErrorHandle()
               {
                   return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
               }
           }
       }
   ```

   ...

   ```
   // code inside Global.asax.cs MvcApplication class
   protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       Exception ex = Server.GetLastError();

       //Add some logging here

       if(ex.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(typeof(HttpException)))
       {
               //Possibly log that you're redirecting the user
               Response.Clear();
               Response.Redirect("~/");
       }
   }
   ```

   This is easy part.

---

2. Another way I discover is create HttpHandler or HttpModule. I am new in MVC and Asp.Net world and HttpHandler is not working allways for me, because it works only once, then only when application change page, but it not detect Url created by user (only first time). HttpModule work allways for me, but I don't know if it is good or bad. It is little harder then 1. point but you don't need Application_Error and httpErrors in Web.Config.

   If you have httpErrors and Application_Error, delete it and create Module (Right click on `Project > Add new Item > In search put "module" > and select Asp.Net Module.` It create module class with `Init` and `Dispose` methods. Then create your own method and register it to `BeginRequest`.

And here is code for my HttpModule

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Linq;

namespace MyWebApp
{
    public class ErrorHttpModule : IHttpModule
    {
        #region IHttpModule Members

        public void Dispose()
        {
            //clean-up code here.
        }

        public void Init(HttpApplication context)
        {
            // Below is an example of how you can handle LogRequest event and provide 
            // custom logging implementation for it
            // context.LogRequest += new EventHandler(OnLogRequest);
            context.BeginRequest += new EventHandler(BR); // register your own method in to Event where you check Url
        }

        #endregion

        private HttpContext context = null;

        public void BR(Object source, EventArgs e)
        {
            context = System.Web.HttpContext.Current;
            // collect all controllers in web application
            Assembly asm = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(MyWebApp.MvcApplication)); // need using System.Reflection;

            var controlleractionlist = asm.GetTypes()
                    .Where(type => typeof(System.Web.Mvc.Controller).IsAssignableFrom(type)) // need using System.Linq;
                    .SelectMany(type => type.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | BindingFlags.Public))
                    .Where(m => !m.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute), true).Any())
                    .Select(x => new { Controller = x.DeclaringType.Name, Action = x.Name, ReturnType = x.ReturnType.Name, Attributes = String.Join(",", x.GetCustomAttributes().Select(a => a.GetType().Name.Replace("Attribute", ""))) })
                    .OrderBy(x => x.Controller).ThenBy(x => x.Action).ToList();


            // Get Url
            string page = "";
            if (context != null)
            {
                page = context.Request.Url.PathAndQuery;
            }

            string newUrl;
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(page))
            {
                bool continute = true;
                // does url contain controller or action?
                foreach (var controller in controlleractionlist)
                {
                    string cpath = "/" + controller.Controller.Replace("Controller", "") + (controller.Action == "Index" ? "" : "/" + controller.Action);
                    if (cpath == page)
                    {
                        // Yes, don't continue to redirect
                        continute = false;
                        break;
                    }
                    else if (page == ("/" + controller.Action))
                    {
                        // Yes, don't continue to redirect
                        continute = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                // does page load your content, script etc.. ?
                if (page.Contains("Content/") == true
                    || page.Contains("Scripts/") == true
                    || page.Contains(".ico") == true
                    || page == "/"
                    )
                {
                    // Yes, don't redirect.
                    continute = false;
                }
                if (continute)


   {
                    // anything else will redirect to Home page
                    var urlHelper = new UrlHelper(context.Request.RequestContext); // nned using System.Web.Mvc;
                    newUrl = urlHelper.Action("About", "Home");
                    context.Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently";
                    context.Response.AddHeader("Location", newUrl);
                    context.Response.End();
                }
            }
        }

        public void OnLogRequest(Object source, EventArgs e)
        {
            //custom logging logic can go here
        }
    }
}
```

And finnaly add module in to Web.Config (on Project level (ProjectName > Web.Config), not inside folder under Project (ProjectName > View > Web.Config))

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <add name="MyHttpErrorModule" type="MyWebApp.ErrorHttpModule, MyWebApp"/>
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
```

---

### Extended question

Either first or second point, I have problem with both, when in url is put characters like that `/abc=45%$#r`. It leads to `Bad Request - Invalid URL HTTP Error 400. The request URL is invalid.` and this don't detect Application_Error, httpErrors in Web.Config or my HttpModule with BeginRequest. Therefore I think this is on IIS settings but what I need to set up? It looks like those characters make IIS mess `%$`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you'll need to set errors to pass through in IIS so that your application can handle the file/parameter links instead of IIS. Add the below to your `Web.config`:

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />
</system.webServer>
```

If you want to redirect to your home page (without any extra parameters in the URL) when you get an issue with a user going to the wrong controller/action, add the following code to your `Global.asax.cs`.

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Exception ex = Server.GetLastError();

    //Add some logging here

    if(ex.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(typeof(HttpException)))
    {
            //Possibly log that you're redirecting the user
            Response.Clear();
            Response.Redirect("~/");
    }
}
```

Basically, what this is is doing is making all errors in your ASP.NET MVC website go through this method. Then it checks to see if the exception is a `HttpException`. If it is, it will redirect to your home controller and action. If it is not a `HttpException` it will continue doing the error handling process. This way you can keep handling the important errors properly.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately it working only when controller is missing. When I put something like /abc.d this function is never called (tested from debuger) and error 404 File Not Found is displayed. How to redirect from FileNotFound error when Application_Error function doesn't catch it?

Comment: @Wanderer you can add another if statement to catch that exception as well. I'll update my answer in a bit and give an example.

Comment: @Wanderer, just realized that if the user is accessing a file like in your example, that gets handled by IIS and not your application. IIS is the web server hosting software. If it doesn't choose to give the application the error, we won't be able to catch it in the application. There is a setting to turn that off in IIS to let your application handle it. I'll do some research and update my answer.

Comment: @Wanderer Sorry for the wait, updated the answer with a step to turn off IIS 404 errors.

Comment: Thanks try help, but it didn't work, I got this text `resource you are looking for has been removed, ...` But this working for me 
    `<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
      <remove statusCode="404"/>
      <error statusCode="404" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/Error/ErrorHandle"/>
      <remove statusCode="400"/>
      <error statusCode="400" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/Error/ErrorHandle"/>
    ` with this settings I can type almost anything except `/qwe/rty/ui.po=4&%$` I got `Bad RequestHTTP Error 400. The request URL is invalid.`

Comment: @Wanderer , I'm glad that is working for you. The httpErrors config example I gave works on my machine but you know how that goes. You might have different settings than my default project that could affect the configuration (which is fine since you've got a solution).

Comment: I extend question, if You know answer, you can update your answer. Thanks.

Comment: @Wanderer, updated the answer but I think this is the best it's going to get. Apparently, you can't get past the % sign in IIS... [see this answer for details](https://serverfault.com/questions/257680/properly-handle-iis-request-with-percent-sign-in-url)